# Can I remove a single value from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to remove a single value from a key:values combination.
For example, when having the following dictionary:

```
d = {1: [2, 3, 4, 7], 2: [1, 3, 4]}
```

I'd like to remove the key:value 1:2, so that the dictionary becomes:

```
{1: [3, 4, 7], 2: [1, 3, 4]}
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a dict that holds lists.

The lists can be manipulated in the usual manner

```
d = {1: [2, 3, 4, 7], 2: [1, 3, 4]}

d[1].remove(2)

print(d)

# {1: [3, 4, 7], 2: [1, 3, 4]}
```

Comment: With the mention that it's d[1].remove(2), many thanks for the complete answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, first find a reference to list, then remove an item with value `2` from list, so:

```
d[1].remove(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {1: [2, 3, 4, 7], 2: [1, 3, 4]}
d[1].remove(2)
print d
```