# How can I delete or modify values in a dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Im having problems trying to figure out how to remove the value "100" from the key "Math" in my "grades" dictionary. I have tried using pop() but i cant use the location grades['math'].pop(0) i need to delete the value from a user input :
`gradeDelete = int(input("Which grade do you want to delete?: ")`

```
grades = {"english":[90,95,81],
      "math":[100,95,92,98],
      "history":[76,98]}
```

Thank you in advance for your help

I have tried the following code but i cant use it with an user input

```
grades['math'].append()
grades.popitem()
grades['math'].pop(1)
```

Comment: have you tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472835/can-i-remove-a-single-value-from-a-dictionary) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I remove a single value from a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28472835/can-i-remove-a-single-value-from-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

`itemToRemove = int(input("Enter the value to remove from 'math'"))`
`grades["math"].remove(itemToRemove)`

Answer (score 0):

The `pop` method takes the index of value as an argument so you need to find the index of value you want to pop. E.g.

```py
grades = {"english": [90, 95, 81],
          "math": [100, 95, 92, 98],
          "history": [76, 98]}


def pop_by_value(list_: list, value_):
    for i, val_ in enumerate(list_):
        if val_ == value_:
            return list_.pop(i)
    raise ValueError(f"No {value_} in list.")


poped = pop_by_value(grades['math'], 100)


print(grades['math'])
```

Comment: As there already exists a `remove` method in python which removes by value, implementing your own version of this is usually not a good idea.

Comment: You're right. Built-in methods are usually one of the best choices, but I don't know all of them, so sometimes I use my own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on sachin's answer, this is how I interpreted your request :

```py
    itemToRemove = int(input("Which grade do you want to delete?: "))
    // iterate through dict
    for value in grades.values():
        // for each list in dict, ensuring list is not empty
        if value:
            // remove each occurrance of "itemToRemove" from list : 
            while itemToRemove in value: value.remove(itemToRemove)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to add description of what your code does (removing **all** grades with the specified value). Also, this does not only remove grades from "math". Lastly, I believe the `if value` guard is unnecessary, as `itemToRemove in value` is False if the list is empty (and I would not expect it to be None)

Answer (score 0):

To make it more a little bit dynamic you can use following code, which helping you to remove data from a specific subject

```
grades = {
    "english":[90,  95, 81],
    "math":   [100, 95, 92, 98],
    "history":[76, 98]
}

def remove_data_from_subject():
    subject = str(input(
        "Which subject data do you want to delete?: ")
    )

    while subject not in grades:
        subject = str(input(
            "Invalid subject. Please enter a valid subject: ")
        )
        
    removed_item = int(input(
        f"Enter the value to remove from {subject}: ")
    )

    while removed_item not in grades[subject]:
        removed_item = int(input(
            "Value not found in subject. Please enter a valid value: ")
        )
        
    grades[subject].remove(removed_item)
    print(grades)

remove_data_from_subject()
```

### How to use

1. First you need to specify the subject

`Which subject data do you want to delete?:` math

2. Then you can fill the value to be removed

`Enter the value to remove from math:` 100

```
Result:  {'english': [90, 95, 81], 'math': [95, 92, 98], 'history': [76, 98]}
```

If you specify the incorrect `subject` or `value` it will keep asking you until you give it the correct one.